# Draw a QgsPolyLine with QGIS C++ API

Tags: qgis, line, c++

I have a simple polyline with three points. I want to draw it on a `QgsVectorLayer`, but can't seem to get it working. I am able to draw a simple geometry on the layer, but that doesn't allow for styling the line (setting the color, line thickness, line ends, etc.). To do that I need to use a feature, or ideally I would just use a `QgsArrowSymbolLayer`. But there doesn't seem to be a way to actually set the line's points without calling `QgsArrowSymbolLayer::renderPolyline`. However that function requires a `QgsSymbolRenderContext` and I have NO IDEA how to grab the context so I can't call the function. This is incredibly frustrating.

I have considered even just figuring out how to call Python plugins from within my custom C++ application because this is so confusing.

Here is my nonworking code.

```
 // Create a polygon
 QPolygonF polyline;
 polyline.push_back(QPointF(10, 10));
 polyline.push_back(QPointF(20, 20));
 polyline.push_back(QPointF(30, 10));

 QgsArrowSymbolLayer *layer = new QgsArrowSymbolLayer();
 // layer->renderPolyline(polyline, <the_context_would_go_here>); (I WANT THIS TO WORK)
```

How do I do this? Or, if you know how to load custom python plugins for QGIS using the C++ API please let me know.